# EPPlus Pivot Table - Collapse entire field

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, openxml, epplus

Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm using EPPlus in .Net and have created a pivot table with 2 row fields and one summary datafield:

```
Dim Pivot As OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.ExcelPivotTable
Pivot = wksPivot.PivotTables.Add(wksPivot.Cells("A1"), Datarange, "pName")

Pivot.RowFields.Add(Pivot.Fields("Fld1")).Sort = Table.PivotTable.eSortType.Ascending
Pivot.RowFields.Add(Pivot.Fields("Fld2")).Sort = Table.PivotTable.eSortType.Ascending

Dim dtaFld As OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.ExcelPivotTableDataField
dtaFld = Pivot.DataFields.Add(Pivot.Fields("XYZ"))
dtaFld.Function = Table.PivotTable.DataFieldFunctions.Sum
```

Everything works great, but I want to have the Pivot Table start off as collapsed when the user opens the workbook (In excel, when you're creating the pivot table, you can right-click in the data element and select "Expand / Collapse" > "Collapse Entire Field"

Hot can I do this via code?? (And I'm willing to use direct OpenXML if EPPlus doesn't support this yet...)

**ALSO**, is there a way to delete out the Raw data from the workbook so that the pivot table still works? i've tried and when I open the workbook, my pivot table is blank? - My current logic has led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346004/openxml-epplus-create-pivotcache-in-net)... Any thoughts??

(I do know I wrote this question in VB. but I added both the `C#` & `VB` tags to this question - I'm comfortable with code in either language - Thanks!!)

Comment: As an add-on to this question since no one has answered it, what I ended up doing was creating the sheet with the datatable using EPPlus for speed, then saving it. THEN, I opened the sheet using the Excel.Interop interface, created the Pivot Table and used  "Field1.ShowDetail = False" to collapse it as i wanted...

Comment: As an add-on to my add-on... The above comment no longer serves me since I now want to move this application over to ASP / IIS and so Excel Interop is no longer a valid possibility...

Answer (score 2):

Could make it xlsm and add vba to it. This is probably the worst answer to this solution but it achives full collapse. I have provided a working example, just copy past into a new console app. add the epplus dependency, "F5".

modified/taken from http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SampleApp/Sample15.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.IO;

namespace pTable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //ExcelPackage _pck = new ExcelPackage();

            Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format("Test"));
            //ExcelPackage _pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("Test\\Worksheet.xlsx"));
            ExcelPackage _pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("Test\\Worksheet.xlsm"));

            var wsPivot1 = _pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Rows-Data on columns");

            var ws = _pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
            ws.Cells["K1"].Value = "Item";
            ws.Cells["L1"].Value = "Category";
            ws.Cells["M1"].Value = "Stock";
            ws.Cells["N1"].Value = "Price";
            ws.Cells["O1"].Value = "Date for grouping";

            ws.Cells["K2"].Value = "Crowbar";
            ws.Cells["L2"].Value = "Hardware";
            ws.Cells["M2"].Value = 12;
            ws.Cells["N2"].Value = 85.2;
            ws.Cells["O2"].Value = new DateTime(2010, 1, 31);

            ws.Cells["K3"].Value = "Crowbar";
            ws.Cells["L3"].Value = "Hardware";
            ws.Cells["M3"].Value = 15;
            ws.Cells["N3"].Value = 12.2;
            ws.Cells["O3"].Value = new DateTime(2010, 2, 28);

            ws.Cells["K4"].Value = "Hammer";
            ws.Cells["L4"].Value = "Hardware";
            ws.Cells["M4"].Value = 550;
            ws.Cells["N4"].Value = 72.7;
            ws.Cells["O4"].Value = new DateTime(2010, 3, 31);

            ws.Cells["K5"].Value = "Hammer";
            ws.Cells["L5"].Value = "Hardware";
            ws.Cells["M5"].Value = 120;
            ws.Cells["N5"].Value = 11.3;
            ws.Cells["O5"].Value = new DateTime(2010, 4, 30);

            ws.Cells["K6"].Value = "Crowbar";
            ws.Cells["L6"].Value = "Hardware";
            ws.Cells["M6"].Value = 120;
            ws.Cells["N6"].Value = 173.2;
            ws.Cells["O6"].Value = new DateTime(2010, 5, 31);

            ws.Cells["K7"].Value = "Hammer";
            ws.Cells["L7"].Value = "Hardware";
            ws.Cells["M7"].Value = 1;
            ws.Cells["N7"].Value = 4.2;
            ws.Cells["O7"].Value = new DateTime(2010, 6, 30);

            ws.Cells["K8"].Value = "Saw";
            ws.Cells["L8"].Value = "Hardware";
            ws.Cells["M8"].Value = 4;
            ws.Cells["N8"].Value = 33.12;
            ws.Cells["O8"].Value = new DateTime(2010, 6, 28);

            ws.Cells["K9"].Value = "Screwdriver";
            ws.Cells["L9"].Value = "Hardware";
            ws.Cells["M9"].Value = 1200;
            ws.Cells["N9"].Value = 45.2;
            ws.Cells["O9"].Value = new DateTime(2010, 8, 31);

            ws.Cells["K10"].Value = "Apple";
            ws.Cells["L10"].Value = "Groceries";
            ws.Cells["M10"].Value = 807;
            ws.Cells["N10"].Value = 1.2;
            ws.Cells["O10"].Value = new DateTime(2010, 9, 30);

            ws.Cells["K11"].Value = "Butter";
            ws.Cells["L11"].Value = "Groceries";
            ws.Cells["M11"].Value = 52;
            ws.Cells["N11"].Value = 7.2;
            ws.Cells["O11"].Value = new DateTime(2010, 10, 31);
            ws.Cells["O2:O11"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

            var pt = wsPivot1.PivotTables.Add(wsPivot1.Cells["A1"], ws.Cells["K1:N11"], "Pivottable1");

            pt.Compact = true;
            pt.CompactData = true;

            pt.GrandTotalCaption = "Total amount";
            pt.RowFields.Add(pt.Fields[1]);
            pt.RowFields.Add(pt.Fields[0]);
            pt.DataFields.Add(pt.Fields[3]);
            pt.DataFields.Add(pt.Fields[2]);
            pt.DataFields[0].Function = DataFieldFunctions.Product;
            pt.DataOnRows = false;



            _pck.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine("Private Sub Workbook_Open()");
            sb.AppendLine("    Range(\"A1\").Select");
            sb.AppendLine("    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(\"Pivottable1\").PivotFields(\"Category\").PivotItems(\"Hardware\").ShowDetail = False");
            sb.AppendLine("End Sub");

            _pck.Workbook.CodeModule.Code = sb.ToString();

            _pck.Save();


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You know what, @FaceToDesk, I was thinking about doing this over and over again and HOPING there was a better solution, but it REALLY doesn't seem there is one based upon the lack of responses this question has been getting. Thank you SO much, I think you're 100% right and this is the best way to deal with the problem!!!

Comment: I'm thinking I'm going to mix this up with having the `Workbook_Open` Sub delete itself after being run the first time... Like shown here: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/532200-how-to-remove-workbook_open-macro.html. I'll post up my final code once I'm done to show anyone else who ever has this kind of issue what can be done. Just for the sake of HOPING I can get another solution, I'm not going to mark you as the correct answer just yet (Still hoping someone out there has another answer), but you definitely deserve the bounty!! Thank you SO MUCH for your help!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Using EPPlus you could try something like (Taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464047/how-to-set-pivot-table-report-layout-to-tabular-in-epplus)):

```
(from pf in pivot.Fields
 select pf).ToList().ForEach(f =>
 {
     f.Compact = false;
     f.Outline = false;
 });
```

or perhaps more simply, doesn't something like the following work?

```
pvtTable.Compact = False
pvtTable.CompactData = False
pvtTable.Outline = False
pvtTable.OutlineData = False
pvtTable.ShowDrill = True
```

Also look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479192/creating-pivot-table-in-excel-using-open-xml-and-c-sharp) detailing a nice reverse engineer method for seeing how excel achieves 'things'.

P.S. Can't help you with your other 'also' question sorry.

Comment: Paul, it doesn't seem to change the pivottable to fully collapsed... Were you able to accomplish it using this code?? Thanks for the response!!!!