# Creating Pivot Table in Excel using Open XML and C#

Tags: c#, openxml, pivot-table

I used store a data into the DataTable and wants to create a Pivot Table using this data.

I have gone through many posts and also read the Microsoft's documentation on creating Pivot table through Open XML but couldn't get the solution. Can anyone please post some code to create Pivot table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Open XML SDK](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124&ei=LRBIUcW2KMebO86ogcgK&usg=AFQjCNFVh7-OHeQJmw_KdtM4Cws37jGYbw&sig2=-Aa_eTuVdbI-uknFVWTO_Q&bvm=bv.43828540,d.d2k), it contains a tool called Open XML SDK Productivity Tool.

How to use it:

Open Excel and create a file containing a Pivot table. Save it and open it with the Productivity Tool. In this tool is an option to 'Reflect the code', that way you can see how to create the same Excel by using C# code.

Comment: While this is technically correct, it's a bit like suggesting the best way to learn how to build a car is to look at a list of the atoms that are in it.

Comment: @ChrisRae Thank you for this useful comment. But ... it would have been even better if you had used your time to come up with a more helpful answer.

Comment: Yes true. I was unfortunately looking for the answer myself... there's some stuff at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278324.aspx but it's not much. The complex part seems to be exact the relationship between the PivotCache and the PivotTable.