# OpenXML / EPPlus - Create PivotCache in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, openxml, epplus

I'm hoping this could help me, at least, answer one of the 2 questions I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846334/epplus-pivot-table-collapse-entire-field), but I am looking how to create a PivotCache in EPPlus / OpenXML and can't find anything online / in their documentation that shows how to do it.

So, suposing I have one Excel sheet, `wksRawData` created in EPPlus and I want to create a second sheet with a pivot table based upon the pivot cache of `wksRawData.Cells(wksRawData.Dimension.Address)` - In the hopes that then I could delete wksRawData but still keep the pivot table. How would I do that?

So far, my code for creating the pivot table in my second worksheet is:

```
  Dim wksRawData As ExcelWorksheet = wbk.Worksheets("Raw Data")
  Dim wksPvtTbl As ExcelWorksheet = wbk.Worksheets("PivotTbl")


 ' Insert the Pivot Table to the sheet
 Dim DataRange As ExcelRange = wksRawData.Cells(wksRawData.Dimension.Address)

 Dim pvtTable As OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.ExcelPivotTable = wksPvtTbl.PivotTables.Add(wksPvtTbl.Cells("B4"), DataRange, "MyPivotTable")

 pvtTable.Compact = True
 pvtTable.CompactData = True
 pvtTable.Outline = True
 pvtTable.OutlineData = True
 pvtTable.ShowHeaders = True
 pvtTable.UseAutoFormatting = True
 pvtTable.ApplyWidthHeightFormats = True
 pvtTable.ShowDrill = True
 pvtTable.RowHeaderCaption = "Caption"

 ' Set the top field
 Dim r1 As OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.ExcelPivotTableField = pvtTable.Fields("FirstField")
 r1.Sort = OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.eSortType.Ascending
 pvtTable.RowFields.Add(r1)

 ' Set the second field
 Dim r2 As OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.ExcelPivotTableField = pvtTable.Fields("SecondField")
 r2.Sort = OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.eSortType.Ascending
 pvtTable.RowFields.Add(r2)
 r2.ShowAll = False

 ' Set the DataField
 Dim df1 As OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.ExcelPivotTableField = pvtTable.Fields("DataField")
 df1.SubTotalFunctions = OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.eSubTotalFunctions.Sum
 pvtTable.DataFields.Add(df1)
```

PLEASE, any and all help on this or the other question would REALLY be appreciated - Whether it be in C# or VB, EPPlus or OpenXML - I just need to get this working!!!

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I belive you want to add data from another sheet. My post in your other thread shows full code [EPPlus Pivot Table - Collapse entire field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846334/epplus-pivot-table-collapse-entire-field)

```
var pt = wsPivot1.PivotTables.Add(wsPivot1.Cells["A1"], ws.Cells["K1:N11"], "Pivottable1");
```

calling "PivoTables.Add()" see tool tip below.

```
// Summary:
//     Create a pivottable on the supplied range
//
// Parameters:
//   Range:
//     The range address including header and total row
//
//   Source:
//     The Source data range address
//
//   Name:
//     The name of the table. Must be unique
//
// Returns:
//     The pivottable object
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're meaning to do here... My challenge is that I want to create the pivot table based upon data in a second sheet and then delete the second sheet. The challenge is that if you delete the second sheet via EPPlus, the pivot table comes up empty when you open the workbook. My logic was to then save the data in a PivotCache (which would then allow me to delete the second sheet), but I can't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: Following your logic from the other Q, I could write code for workbook_open which would delete the second sheet once the pivotcache is automatically created by excel when the workbook opens, but here I'd like to learn how to create the actual cache... Any thoughts?? / What are you suggesting??