# on Startup of Excel file collapse all the drilldowns on an Excel Pivot Table

Tags: c#, .net, excel, pivot-table, epplus

I am fairly new to the Pivot Table concept and I am having some issues with getting an Excel Pivot Table to be collapsed on start up.

I am developing this in .NET 4.5 and C#

The first image is when I start up by excel file, my pivot table has all the drill downs shown.

Example:
[image]

I would like them to be suppressed so It shows a general Summary, then if the user wants to, they can drill down from there. Like so:

[image]

Is there a property from the pivotable I am just not seeing?
currently I have these set on my pivottable...

```
            pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;
            pivotTable.ColumGrandTotals = false;
            pivotTable.Compact = false;
            pivotTable.CompactData = false;
            pivotTable.MultipleFieldFilters = true;
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a limitation of the tool and how it interacts with Excel.  Since the Pivot Table is not actually generated until excel has loaded the file, it cannot be set in the XML of the file prior.  Best you can do is use VBA.  Not pretty if you have security settings imposed but it is something:

[EPPlus Pivot Table - Collapse entire field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846334/epplus-pivot-table-collapse-entire-field)