# How to set column name on pivot table

Tags: vb.net, pivot-table, epplus

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464047/how-to-set-pivot-table-report-layout-to-tabular-in-epplus) I was able to create a pivot table with a tabular layout in EPPlus.

However column headings are not displaying properly.  When I create the pivot table with Excel I get the column headings "GA Category" and "Container":
[image: Pivot table by Excel]

When I create the pivot table through EPPlus I get the column headings "Row Labels" and "Column Labels"
[image: Pivot table by EPPlus]

I was wondering how I can create set the column headings via EPPlus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the column header via EPPLus cannot be done with the current package.  In order to do so I needed to modify ExcelPivotTable.cs in the project, adding this code:

```
public string ColHeaderCaption
{
    get
    {
        return GetXmlNodeString("@colHeaderCaption");
    }
    set
    {
        SetXmlNodeString("@colHeaderCaption");
    }
}
```

It is then possible to set the row & column captions via the PivotTable class:

```
'Sheet containing the data
Dim dataSheet as ExcelWorksheet
dataSheet = package.Workbook.WorkSheets(0)

'Data used on pivot table - default to entire sheet
Dim dataRange as ExcelRangeBase
dataRange = dataSheet.Cells(dataSheet.Dimension.Address)

'New sheet for the pivot table
Dim sheet as ExcelWorkSheet
sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Pivot")
package.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveToStart(sheet.Name)
sheet.View.TabSelected = true

'Create the pivot table
Dim pivot as Table.PivotTable.ExcelPivotTable
pivot = sheet.PivotTables.Add(sheet.Cells("A1"), dataRange, "PivotTable")

'Add row field
pivot.RowFields.Add(pivot.Fields("RowField"))

'Set row caption
pivot.RowHeaderCaption = "My Row Caption"

'Add column field
pivot.ColumnFields.Add(pivot.Fields("ColumnField"))

'Set column caption
pivot.ColumnHeaderCaption = "My Column Caption"
```

If you cannot or do not want to modify EPPlus, you can still add the header to to your pivot table by modifying the XML after the pivot table is created:

```
pivot.PivotTableXml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("colHeaderCaption", "My Column Caption");
```

Comment: You should submit a pull request with this change :). Still +1 for figuring it out.

Comment: FYI I looked at the latest source and your code for setting the caption is there.

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus 5.5.5 gives you the option to set it much easier:

```
pivotTable.RowHeaderCaption = "Account";
pivotTable.ColumnHeaderCaption = "Category";
```