# EPPLUS Pivot Table headers in tabular layout doesn't work

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

I have set the tabular layout according to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464047/how-to-set-pivot-table-report-layout-to-tabular-in-epplus), but the filters on headers pivot table remains in Compact layout with unique "Row Label" in the first header with all filters.

Microsoft Compact/Tabular Layout
[image: Microsoft Compact/Tabular Layout]

[image: This is my result]

[This is the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVa7n.png)

I think this is a bug of EPPLUS, does anyone have any solution?

I use version 6.1.1.0 of EPPLUS

This is the configuration of my pivot table :

```
pivotTable.ColumnGrandTotals = true;
pivotTable.Compact = false;
pivotTable.CompactData = false;
pivotTable.DataCaption = "Values";
pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;
pivotTable.ErrorCaption = "[error]";
pivotTable.GridDropZones = true;
pivotTable.Outline = false;
pivotTable.OutlineData = false;
pivotTable.RowGrandTotals = true;
pivotTable.ShowColumnHeaders = true;
pivotTable.ShowError = true;
pivotTable.ShowHeaders = true;
pivotTable.ShowMemberPropertyTips = false;
pivotTable.ShowValuesRow = false;
```

This is the how I add the fields in RowFields :

```
var field = pivotTable.Fields[fieldName];
field.Outline = false;
field.Compact = false;
field.SubTotalFunctions = eSubTotalFunctions.None;
field = pivotTable.RowFields.Add(field);
field.ShowDropDowns = true;
field.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution , set Outline and Compact to false for each fields of pivot table.

```
pivotTable.Fields.ForEach(field => { field.Outline = false; field.Compact = false; });
```